# Issue with string.Contains and special characters

Tags: c#, char

I have a list of objects, those objects have a property named `Date` which is actually a `string` (not my fault and *I can't change it*).

`ObjectsList[0].Date` returns `"08/07/2014 07:55:00"`, but I don't know why, if I do `.Contains("07/2014")` it returns `true` and `.Contains("8/07/2014")` returns `false`.

Is this a *escaping* issue? Is there any way to *escape special characters* on `string.Contains`?

Comment: It is doing what it is suppose to.  You get true becuase date contains 07/2014 but not 8/072014 however, if you do 08/07/2014 you will get true.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BAayvT

Comment: no, `Contains` match strings literally. You need to dump the actual characters as hex to make sure that there's no invisible characters

Comment: @AliK wrong. The original string contains both search strings

Comment: Do a `foreach(char c in ObjectsList[0].Date) Console.WriteLine(c);` and you will see if there are any strange characters in the string.

Comment: @phuclv I'm going to try it

Comment: @Magnus I'm going to try it

Comment: `string dump = string.Join(" ", ObjectsList[0].Date.Select(c => $"'{c}' (\\u{((int)c):x4})")); Console.Write(dump);`

Comment: I wonder Your code returns true in my system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Contains` doesn't return `true`, there's no such substring in the string. To find out what *invisible* symbol which spoils the fun, let's have a look at the *dump*:

```
using System.Linq;

...
string dump = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ObjectsList[0].Date
  .Select(c => $"'{c}' (\\u{((int)c):x4})")); 
        
Console.Write(dump);
```

Expected output:

```
'0' (\u0030)
'8' (\u0038) <- Some wrong character(s) is expected here
'/' (\u002f)
'0' (\u0030)
'7' (\u0037)
'/' (\u002f)
'2' (\u0032)
'0' (\u0030)
'1' (\u0031)
'4' (\u0034)
' ' (\u0020)
'0' (\u0030)
'7' (\u0037)
':' (\u003a)
'5' (\u0035)
'5' (\u0035)
':' (\u003a)
'0' (\u0030)
'0' (\u0030)
```

But you are going to have a *different* one. To get rid of *unwanted* characters you can use Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

...
// Keep only digits '0'..'9', space ' ' and delimiters ':', '/'
string cleared = string.Concat(ObjectsList[0]
  .Date
  .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c) || " :/".Contains(c)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare times use this code

```
 foreach (var item in ObjectsList)
    {
        if (string.Equals(item.Date, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("false");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please note, that `mm` stands for *minutes*, not *months* (`MM`)

Comment: As you can see, `item.Date` has time of day part, e.g. `"08/07/2014 07:55:00"` and you format string provides date only, so `string.Equals` will be **ever** `false`

Comment: Thank you . but in the question he just check for the date . not time